# erlIDE compiler options

Tags: erlang, erlide

How do I specify compiler options in erlIDE? The answer to the question [Erlang: add libraries to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315279/erlang-add-libraries-to-application) is to add required libraries to the compiler options but i cant see how to do this with erlIDE ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to specify additional include directories for your libraries, there is a field for that in 0.15.3. I had removed it by mistake in 0.15.2, I hope it's not been too big a problem.

0.15.3 is available at the moment from http://erlide.org/update_beta and will be promoted soon to an official release.

If there are other compiler settings that you need, then you will have to let me know which ones and I will add them. In this case, please open a ticket at https://github.com/erlide/erlide/issues

Comment: Thanks Vlad that explains it, keep up the good work with erlIDE! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> Erlang -> Compiler -> Compiler options in Erlang format.

But generally you do not need to use this if your project uses some kind of build tool like [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar).

Comment: Thanks Blinkov however I have no option "Compiler options in Erlang format". Just check boxes under the title "Select the compiler options to be used by default". Im using the latest erlIDE I believe version 0.15.2201203201350.

Comment: Well, then it seems like this really depends on the build of erlIDE. Maybe you just need to try some older one?