# build path for external libraries erlide

Tags: erlide

I am working on an erlang application using couchbeam. I am new in erlang and it would be easier for me to work in erlide.

I have used eclipse in java and It was easy to add external libraries. I tried to find out how to build path for those external libraries in erlide but I did not find any solution. when I looked at the asked questions, I found out that the 
[Erlang: add libraries to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315279/erlang-add-libraries-to-application) should be smilar to my question but I did not understand how it has been done because it is different from how we did while adding external jar files for example!

If no solution I would ask if there is any one who can help me fix the same question in Emacs

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using basho's [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) to compile Erlang projects, it's like **ant** or **maven** for Java and more or less an industry standard in Erlang world. It allows to easily manage all kind of dependencies and compile/release projects.

Also I'd recommend to check out [SublimErl](https://github.com/ostinelli/SublimErl) as an alternative to Erlide. Much more lightweight and comfortable.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I created an webmachine application using rebar  and I can run it on my localhost:8000. But the question I have is how to link my application to the couchDB using couchbeam for displaying queries on my webbased interface(html page)! I am sorry if the question is stupid but I am really new in web application and erlang world.

Answer (score 0):

Erlide has currently no easy way to configure projects that use external libraries. We're working on a solution for that. In the meanwhile, here are some ways to make it work today:

- create a project for couchdb and refer to it from your project; if you disable the erlang builder for the project, erlide will not try to build couch
- create linked folders in your project that point to the couchdb ones, so that it looks like they are part of your project; you can choose to only link the include directory, and then erlide will not try to compile couch, but you can not navigate the couch code (it's unavailable to erlide)

For building your project, it is indeed better to have a way to do that outside Eclipse (be it emake, rebar or make). We are also working on a way to use these tools from erlide.

Please let me know if you need further assistance.